# Get $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ from $2x(\frac{dy}{dx}) = \frac{dy}{dt}$

Tags: differential

I stumbled upon this on a "worked solutions manual"
But I dont quite understand the part I selected in red.
[![This is the working out they show][1]][1]

How can $ \frac{dy}{dt}$ be converted to $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$  when differentiating with respect to $x$?

Im probably missing something...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ3FC.jpg

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2x}\frac{dy}{dt},~\frac{dx}{dt}=2x$$
Then $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dy}{dx})(\frac{dt}{dx})=\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{1}{2x} \frac{dy}{dt}\right)\frac{1}{2x}$$
$$=\left(\frac{-1}{2x^2}\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{1}{2x}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\right)\frac{1}{2x}=\frac{1}{4x^2}\left(\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-2\frac{dy}{dt}\right)$$